# Is there a way to create multiple consoles in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, console

It seems all the "Multiple Consoles in C++" questions on this site are either 7 years old and no longer work, or are in C instead of C++. I've searched the web for any APIs for something of that nature. Is there a way specifically to create multiple consoles in C++?

Comment: The Windows API doesn't change much. In all likeliness, if you find an article that was published a decade or two ago, it's probably still accurate. Besides, the Windows API is exposed purely as a C interface. Using C++ doesn't buy you **anything** in terms of features.

Comment: You can't have more than one console attached to a process, but a single console can have multiple [console buffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers) (which can be swapped). If you want more than one console, you will need to create an additional process for each console. See [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) on how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole says no you can't do that within a single process.

> A process can be attached to at most one console. If the calling process is already attached to a console, the error code returned is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (5).

This also repeats the theme: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole

> A process can be associated with only one console, so the AllocConsole function fails if the calling process already has a console. A process can use the FreeConsole function to detach itself from its current console, then it can call AllocConsole to create a new console or AttachConsole to attach to another console.

As [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) mentioned in a comment, you can however spawn additional child processes each having their own console windows. See the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag of CreateProcess here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags

Comment: So I can create multiple windows in GLFW but I can't create multiple consoles....... Makes sense..

Comment: You can, however, spawn new processes that are associated with their own console windows. See the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag of `CreateProcess()`.

Comment: The term [*console*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_console) dates back to 1959 and represents a line-oriented, text-mode user interface. Traditionally text-mode applications had access to at most one console, but multiple applications can share a console. Windows, Linux, macOS and other OSes all follow this convention. For a multi-window experience there is GUI interface.